# Using existing VF page in Lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, migration, pagemessages

We need to use existing VF pages in lightning experiences. We changed the styling using standard attribute lightningStylesheets="true".

But apex:pageMessages seems to be not working on those VF pages.Can we do something for this? Otherwise  we need to remove apex:pagemessages from all our pages and use some other way to display errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_lightningstylesheets.htm), The apex:pageMessages is supported in Lightning with lightningstylesheet=true without any additional style.

I have checked and verified it using below code:-

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opportunities"
    tabStyle="Opportunity" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <p>Enter an alphabetic character for the "Close Date," 
       then click Save to see what happens.</p>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunities}" var="opp">
                <apex:column value="{!opp.name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Close Date">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opp.closeDate}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. Acutualy, I was showing the page message on constructor. It was visible on classic but on lightning it didn't got displayed. So I added it inside the output panel and rendered it true with a flag inside constructor. Now It worked.